# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'check' in 'on clause' codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Помогите пожалуйста, столкнулся с такой проблемой! 
Есть такой же запрос с отелями, но с ними все хорошо и не каких ошибок! А вот с недвижимостью проблема такого рода!

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'check' in 'on clause'
>
> > SELECT * FROM (`catalog`) JOIN `nedvizhimost` ON
> >     `nedvizhimost`.`product_id`=`catalog`.`product_id` JOIN
> >     `check-nedvizh` ON `check`-`nedvizh`.`product_id=catalog`.`product_id`
> >     WHERE `id_district` LIKE '%%' AND `id_city` LIKE '%%' AND
> >     `id_type_nedvizh` LIKE '%%' AND `time_zaezda` LIKE '%%' AND
> >     `time_viezda` LIKE '%%' AND `count_guest` LIKE '%%' AND
> >     `id_interval_price` LIKE '%%' AND `count_root` LIKE '%%' AND `kosher`
> >     LIKE '%0%' AND `osobenniy` LIKE '%0%' ORDER BY `name` asc
>
> Filename: /var/www/mishatest/data/www/mrdt.ru/models/catalog.php
>
> Line Number: 42

Код модели:

```
    function search_nedvizhimost($nedvizh){

    $this->db->select('*');        
    $this->db->from($this->catalog_table);  
    $this->db->join($this->nedvizhimost_table, $this->nedvizhimost_table.'.product_id='.$this->catalog_table.'.product_id');
    $this->db->join($this->check_nedvizh_table, $this->check_nedvizh_table.'.product_id='.$this->catalog_table.'.product_id');
    $this->db->order_by('name','asc');              
    $array = array( 'id_district' => $nedvizh['district'], 'id_city' => $nedvizh['city'], 'id_type_nedvizh' => $nedvizh['type_nedvizh'], 
    'time_zaezda' => $nedvizh['ot_hidden'], 'time_viezda' => $nedvizh['do_hidden'], 'count_guest' => $nedvizh['count_guest'], 
    'id_interval_price' => $nedvizh['interval_price'], 'count_root' => $nedvizh['count_root'], 'kosher' => $nedvizh['kosher'], 
    'osobenniy' => $nedvizh['osobenniy'] );     
    $this->db->like($array);        
    $query = $this->db->get();  <--- 42 строка
    return $result = $query->result_array();


}
```

Переменные:

```
protected $name_nedvizhimost_table = 'name-nedvizhimost';
protected $nedvizhimost_table = 'nedvizhimost';

protected $check_name_nedvizh_table = 'name-check-nedvizh'; 
protected $check_nedvizh_table = 'check-nedvizh';
```

И сам скрипт обработки запроса

```
$('body').on('click', '#search_appartament', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 

        $.ajax({    
            url: "/index/index/",       
            type: "post",
            data: $('#form_appartament').serialize(),               
            global: false,
            dataType: "json",
            response:'text',
            cache: false, 
            async: false,
            error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message' + err); },
            success: function(data) { 

                //$('#del').remove();

                alert(data);

                for ( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {

                    var img = '';
                    for ( var j=0; j<data[i].id_level; j++ ) {                      
                        if ( j<5 ) { img = img + '<img src="/images/star.png" alt="Star" />'; } else {
                                     img = img + '<strong style="font-size:18px;"> DLX</strong>'; break; }                          
                    }  

                    var strPost = '<tr>'
                        +'<td>'
                            +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'
                                +'<img src="/images/catalog/tmb/'+data[i].preview+'" alt="" width="193" height="147" />'
                            +'</a>'
                        +'</td>'
                        +'<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 16px;">'
                            +'<div class="ar_levels">'+img+'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_title">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">'+data[i].name+'</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_desc">'+data[i].textarea.substr(0,232)+'...</div>'
                            +'<div class="ar_more">'
                                +'<a href="/catalog/nedvizhimost/'+data[i].alias+'">Подробнее &gt;</a>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</td>'
                    +'</tr>';                               

                    $('#tabl > tbody').append(strPost);

                }

            }

        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас таблицы с названием через дефис, MYSQL это не понимает такие названия без кавычек. Вот такое название таблицы, через нижнее подчеркивание MYSQL поймет:

```
SELECT * FROM check_ned;
```

А вот такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM check-ned
```

Вызовет ошибку, но это можно исправить с помощью кавычек

```
SELECT * FROM `check-ned`
```

Я рекомендую вам именовать таблицы через **нижнее подчеркивание**, потому что это можно **в какой-то степени** считать общепринятой практикой во многих командах и это позволяет избежать подобных проблем.

Вернемся к вопросу, у вас ошибка в запросе:

```
`check-nedvizh` ON `check`-`nedvizh`
```

Видимо, это автоматическое приведение как-то срабатывает на подобное название и оно автоматический конвертируется.

Вероятно в билдере есть проблема, связанная с экранированием названий таблиц подобного плана и оно не учитывает данный символ и разбивает его на  2 части.

Можно попробовать в condition передавать уже названия таблиц заключенные в обратные кавычки, возможно это что-нибудь изменит, но не могу быть уверен, что это поможет. Вероятно, в лучшем случае необходимо искать обновление, или в худшем искать ошибку в самом билдере, а может использовать какой-нибудь прямой запрос к базе без билдера.

```
    $this->db->join($this->nedvizhimost_table, 
'`'.$this->nedvizhimost_table.'`.product_id='.$this->catalog_table.'.product_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

В sql запросе во втором ON виден пробел после check

```
ON check -nedvizh.product_id=
```

Не в этом ли проблема?

Comment: Если вы не уверены, то можете уточнить у автора используя комментарий и не спешить с ответом.